# Exception: No authentication handlers could be resolved to support the authentication transaction: CAS-AD

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, cas

I'm using CAS 5.3.2 to authenticate with Active directory. 
It show `Authenticat fail` and I saw another exception following it:

```
2018-09-12 10:27:27,732 WARN [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.InitialAuthenticationAttemptWebflowEventResolver] - <null>
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException: null
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cc83f6b3.authenticate(<generated>) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager.handle(DefaultAuthenticationTransactionManager.java:29) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.handleAuthenticationTransaction(DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.java:48) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.handleInitialAuthenticationTransaction(DefaultAuthenticationSystemSupport.java:34) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.InitialAuthenticationAttemptWebflowEventResolver.resolveInternal(InitialAuthenticationAttemptWebflowEventResolver.java:80) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.resolve(AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.java:413) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.resolver.impl.AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.resolveSingle(AbstractCasWebflowEventResolver.java:418) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy163.resolveSingle(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.actions.AbstractAuthenticationAction.doExecute(AbstractAuthenticationAction.java:56) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor246.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.execute(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:168) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:216) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:470) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:1.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy158.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.0.RELEASE.jar:2.5.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) ~[servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:30) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.cas.security.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:261) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.cas.security.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:237) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.cas.security.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:94) ~[cas-server-security-filter-2.0.10.2.jar:2.0.10.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:91) ~[cas-server-core-logging-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:130) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:105) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:123) ~[spring-boot-1.5.14.RELEASE.jar:1.5.14.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66) ~[inspektr-common-1.8.3.GA.jar:1.8.3.GA]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71) ~[log4j-web-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2500) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2489) ~[tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-util.jar:8.0.32]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.security.GeneralSecurityException: No authentication handlers could be resolved to support the authentication transaction
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.getAuthenticationHandlersForThisTransaction(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:270) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.authenticateInternal(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:329) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager.java:144) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.apereo.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$90e801d3.invoke(<generated>) ~[cas-server-core-authentication-api-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:84) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.apereo.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:135) ~[inspektr-audit-1.8.3.GA.jar:1.8.3.GA]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:627) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:616) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:45) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.MeteredMethodInterceptor.invoke(MeteredMethodInterceptor.java:32) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:46) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.CountedMethodInterceptor.invoke(CountedMethodInterceptor.java:32) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[metrics-spring-3.1.3.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671) ~[spring-aop-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
    ... 135 more
```

I think root cause is `No authentication handlers could be resolved to support the authentication transaction` . But I don't know what it means and how to solve it.
My cas config file:

```
cas.server.name: http://86.2.58.119:8081
cas.server.prefix: http://86.2.58.119:8081/cas

cas.adminPagesSecurity.ip=0\.0\.0\.0

logging.config: file://C:/etc/cas/config/log4j2.xml
# cas.serviceRegistry.config.location: classpath:/services

# SSL
server.ssl.enabled=false

cas.serviceRegistry.initFromJson=true
cas.serviceRegistry.json.location=file://C:/etc/cas/json

cas.monitor.endpoints.enabled:                    true
endpoints.enabled:                                true

cas.monitor.endpoints.sensitive:        false
endpoints.sensitive:                    false

cas.adminPagesSecurity.loginUrl:        ${cas.server.prefix}/login
cas.adminPagesSecurity.service:         ${cas.server.prefix}/status/dashboard
#cas.adminPagesSecurity.users:           file:/etc/cas/config/admusers.properties
cas.adminPagesSecurity.actuatorEndpointsEnabled:  true
cas.adminPagesSecurity.adminRoles[0]:   ROLE_ADMIN

cas.tgc.path=/cas
cas.tgc.maxAge=-1
cas.tgc.domain=bctt
cas.tgc.name=TGC
cas.tgc.secure=false
cas.tgc.httpOnly=true
cas.tgc.rememberMeMaxAge=1209600

cas.sso.allowMissingServiceParameter=true
cas.sso.createSsoCookieOnRenewAuthn=true
cas.sso.proxyAuthnEnabled=false
cas.sso.renewAuthnEnabled=false

cas.authn.accept.users=
#admin::abc12345,casuser::Mellon

##
# Ldap Authentication
#

# Interesting part for Active Directory:
cas.authn.ldap[0].type=AD
cas.authn.ldap[0].ldapUrl=ldap://86.2.58.118:389

cas.authn.ldap[0].useSsl=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].useStartTls=false
cas.authn.ldap[0].connectTimeout=5000

cas.authn.ldap[0].baseDn=OU=User Account,OU=CAS,DC=liferayadmin,DC=net
cas.authn.ldap[0].searchFilter=sAMAccountName={username}
cas.authn.ldap[0].subtreeSearch=true

# AD manager user like someone@company.com
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindDn=CN=casAdmin,OU=Service Accounts,OU=CAS,DC=liferayadmin,DC=net
cas.authn.ldap[0].bindCredential=abc@*123
cas.authn.ldap[0].dnFormat=cn=%s
#@liferayadmin.net

#cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeId=sAMAccountName
#cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributePassword=
cas.authn.ldap[0].principalAttributeList=sAMAccountName,sn,cn,givenName,displayName

cas.authn.ldap[0].failFast=false

# Default values:
cas.authn.ldap[0].minPoolSize=3
cas.authn.ldap[0].maxPoolSize=10
cas.authn.ldap[0].validateOnCheckout=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].validatePeriodically=true
cas.authn.ldap[0].validatePeriod=600
cas.authn.ldap[0].idleTime=5000
cas.authn.ldap[0].prunePeriod=5000
cas.authn.ldap[0].blockWaitTime=5000

cas.locale.defaultValue=vi
```

I used sAMAccountName/userPassword for user credential. 
Tested with some LDAP client tool, connected succeed. Can get information of users in folder `CAS\UserAccount`.